# Finite-dimensional Inner product space, if $A^{2}x=0 \Rightarrow Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $X$ be a finite inner product space and $A:X\rightarrow X$ a linear
>   transformation. If $A$ is self-adijoint and if $A^{2}x=0$ then $Ax=0$.

Comment: @Vitale It is a duplicate: the answer to the linked question specifically show that $A^2x = 0 \implies Ax = 0$ (using the notation $L$ for $A$, and assuming $A$ is self-adjoint).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using that $A$ is self-adjoint, $A=A^{*}$. Now let $A^{2}x=0$, so we write 
>       down,
>       \begin{eqnarray*}
>     0=(A^{2}x,y)=(Ax,A^{*}y)=(Ax,Ay),~\forall y\in X
>  \end{eqnarray*}
>       just take $y=x$ to get $Ax=0$.